# A hat! I've got a hat!

Tags: discussion

I take it the Christmas hat season has opened? Watch out you werewolves!

Why no announcement this year? I guess SE do it every year, so maybe it's now just taken as routine. However I'm surprised there was no fanfare at all.

**Later:**

This is really a comment, but I don't know how to put pictures in comments. Some of the effects we're getting with hats on the default user images are quite striking. Look at this one (user id concealed to protect the guilty):

[image: User icon]

I don't know if the effect was deliberate or not, but I'd love to see that character on Star Trek.

Comment: For what it's worth, [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/winter-bash-2014/?cb=1) is on the sidebar. Sort of there `-->`.

Comment: I seriously only came to Meta to ask why there wasn't a discussion on it again this year. Beaten to the punch!

Comment: That hat really suits you John. Actually I was slightly disappointed they made adjustable fits: yours was one of the better portraits to see weirdly fitting hats on!

Comment: I completely second @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance . Please sir, [crop it out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19124342#19124342) and make it your permanent profile pic. It befits a guy with 117K! (Sorry for spamming your post!)

Comment: Ironically that hat is the Fear and Loathing hat awarded for deleting your own answer. I got it for deleting my answer to [Is deuterium a boson or a fermion?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153750/is-deuterium-a-boson-or-a-fermion) because I thought [rob](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/44126/rob) posted a much better one. So it's not really a hat one should be proud of :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie: Well, deleting your own answers if you think them to be bad/obsolete/whatever *is* something to be proud of, because it shows you care more about quality than about reputation :)

Comment: @JohnRennie Aw, shucks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What we've posted in the past is not an announcement, really, but a request to find out whether the community wants hats. But the hats have been so well-received in the past that we figured there was no need to ask this year.

I guess an announcement would have been a good idea. We'll keep that in mind for next year. (Yes, it is an annual tradition, or at least we have every reason to expect hats will return each December for the foreseeable future.)

Comment: Hats don't suit me. :-(

Comment: I see you have yours already.

Comment: I love the hats!

Comment: @pfnuesel then there's an "I hate hats" button just for you.